# Is a debt collector allowed to make a hard inquiry on your credit report?

Tags: united-states, debt-collection

Under what circumstances is this permissible? What is the purpose of this anyways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Fair Credit Reporting Act](http://www.ftc.gov/os/statutes/fcradoc.pdf):

> any consumer reporting agency may furnish a consumer report [...] to a person which it has reason to believe [...] intends to use the information in connection with a credit transaction involving the consumer on whom the information is to be furnished and
>   involving the extension of credit to, or review or **collection of an account** of, the consumer

See p12 (section 604). The usual interpretation of this that I've heard is that a debt collection agency that owns or has been assigned a debt can make hard pulls on your credit report without your consent. [This link](http://budgeting.thenest.com/can-debt-collector-make-inquiries-credit-22416.html) seems to support that (and references the same part of the act, among others):

> According to the Fair Credit Reporting Act, [...], **any business can access your credit history without your permission provided the business has a valid "permissible purpose."** The FCRA notes that **one such permissible purpose is to review your credit information in connection with the collection of a debt.** Thus, if you owe money to a debt collector, the debt collector has the legal right to pull and review your credit report.

If they *haven't* been assigned the debt or own it outright, *I believe* you have a legal right to dispute it. Consult a lawyer if this is actually a situation you face.

Once use for this is if the debt collection agency has trouble locating you; since your credit report normally contains current and past addresses, this is one way to locate you.

Comment: Let's assume the debt is valid, but it is reasonably believed that they should have correct contact information on file. What other reasons could they attempt a pull for? Or are they allowed to do blanket pulls on all debtors for whatever reason they wish, if the debts are believed to be valid?

Comment: @Bigbio2002 If you owe them a valid debt (by right of the debt being assigned to them), I believe they can make pulls at their discretion, as many times as they wish. While usually these are soft pulls, I don't think there is a limit to the number of hard pulls they can conduct either. I don't know too much about this area, however, so a lawyer could give you better advice.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll take your 10 points back, muahahaha! Seriously though, I thought your answer was pretty straightforward and hit it on the head.